# Want to get current location in React native 0.55.1

Tags: react-native, geolocation, geocoding

I want to get current location It works for current react native version but i want it for react native version 0.55.1

I  tried in this way
and it works

```
constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        latitude: null,
        longitude: null,
        error:null,
      };
    }
componentDidMount() {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
         (position) => {
           console.log("wokeeey");
           console.log(position);
           this.setState({
             latitude: position.coords.latitude,
             longitude: position.coords.longitude,
             error: null,
           });
         },
         (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
         { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 200000, maximumAge: 1000 },
       );
     }
```

And I printed using this

```
<View>   
    <Text> Longitude:- {this.state.latitude} </Text>
    <Text> Latitude:- {this.state.longitude} </Text>
    <Text> {this.state.error} </Text>  
</View>
```

But for react native 0.55.1 its not working. 
Plz help me what should i Do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For android you should  add below mentioned permission's in android manifest file**

> ```
>  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
>  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
> ```

**Don't forget to enable the GPS in your device**

you can use this method also to get current position

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
         (position) => {
           console.log("wokeeey");
           console.log(position);
           this.setState({
             latitude: position.coords.latitude,
             longitude: position.coords.longitude,
             error: null,
           });
         },
         (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
         { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 200000, maximumAge: 1000 },
       );
```

Comment: Thankz This solved my problem. its not adding those lines